# GDS Gender Scorecard

Tags: looker-studio

As title I would like to show % gender male as scorecard.

So i'm trying this custom metric:

```
gender="male"/(gender="male"+gender="female")*100
```

But I get Syntax error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your data looks like but something like the below is generally what you're after if you have a column that has a count of each gender:

```
sum(CASE WHEN gender='male' THEN YOUR_COUNT_METRIC END)/sum(YOUR_COUNT_METRIC)
```

Or if you have no metric column and a row per person then:

```
sum(CASE WHEN gender='male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/count(gender)
```

If that's not then please post some example data to help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
This is what I would like to create: http://lovesdata.altervista.org/gender-visits.png . 
I`m having problem to create the two metrics showed: 1) % male of total 2) % female of total.

Comment: Hi mauro. I'll edited my answer slightly to give you two examples. If neither suit can you edit your question to include an example of how your data is currently structured?